# JSon data Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jquery

Hi i have one Json call by Ajax the code is

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Voyage.aspx/VoyageVessel_Set",
            data: "{Action:'" + "Set" + "',VesselID:'" + "1" + "',VoyageMasterID:'" + "1" + "',StartTerminalID:'" + "1" + "',LastTerminalID:" + "" + ",EffectiveStartDate:'" + "09/09/09" + "',EffectiveEndDate:'" + "09/09/09" + "',PreviousVoyageID:'" + "1" + "',NextVoyageID:'" + "1" + "',DefaultVoyage:'" + "0" + "',Status:'" + "true" + "'}",
            async: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                try {
                    alert("Success for ADD button");
                    //  $('#dvVesselTaggerInfo').html(html);
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert(ex);
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Because of the Data which im trying to give my method is not calling, i hope i have written it in correct format but still i could not understand whats the probelm, can any one please help me.

Comment: you have two "data:" maybe this will cause issues

Comment: Iam sorry as part of my trial it was 2 but actuly i have tried with one

Comment: I would recommend you to define your data as a javascript object instead of a string and let jQuery to stringify it for you.

Comment: You mean like this var strData = JSON.stringify({ Action: 'Set', VesselID: 1, VoyageMasterID: 1, StartTerminalID: 1, LastTerminalID: 1, EffectiveStartDate: '09 / 09 / 09', EffectiveEndDate: '09 / 09 / 09', PreviousVoyageID: 1, NextVoyageID: 1, DefaultVoyage: 0, Status: 1 });

Answer (score 0):

in your code

> data: "{Action:'" + "Set" + "',VesselID:'" + "1" + "',VoyageMasterID:'" + "1" + "',StartTerminalID:'" + "1" + "',LastTerminalID:" + "" + ",EffectiveStartDate:'" + "09/09/09" + "',EffectiveEndDate:'" + "09/09/09" + "',PreviousVoyageID:'" + "1" + "',NextVoyageID:'" + "1" + "',DefaultVoyage:'" + "0" + "',Status:'" + "true" + "'}",

Generally, each key and value in json data should have quotation marks, e.g:

```
{"Action" : "add", "VesselID", "1"}
```

Hope to help you :)

Comment: I have tried your code , its not working, when i remove parameters of both method and in data the method id getting called, when i give data its not calling